# transform categorical predictors to numerical variable matlab

Tags: matlab, categorical-data, input-parameters

I am new to matlab.
I have a categorical input predictor(X) and the set of past results (Y, binary).
I would like to convert it to numeric variable in the following method.
For each category calculate the average of Y and replace the value with the average.
for example:

```
  X    Y    X'
  1    1    1
  2    0    0
  3    1    0.5
  1    1    1
  2    0    0
  3    0    0.5
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with `mean` function with `Y` as vals and `X` as subs

```
Xprime = accumarray( X, Y, [], @mean );
Xprime = Xptime( X );
```